# How to write some command on a batch file through C++ program?

Tags: c++

I need some help regarding my C++ program. A batch file named `abc.bat` is located somewhere in my hardisk. I know that in C++ I can use this line of code to execute that `abc.bat` file:

`system ("file path here\\abc.bat");`

I want to send some commands to that batch file so that after executing that `abc.bat` file my C++ program should write commands to its console and execute them.  How can I do that?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  You want to send commands to the batch file, but you want the C++ program to execute them?  Please be more clear.

Comment: Thanks  Oli Charlesworth for your prompt response. Let me tell you details, I have a batch file named "monkeyrunner" and i can manually open it then it opens like a command prompt and i write different commands on it and it works fine. Now I am trying to make it programmed, I don't want to open monkeyrunner manually but i want that through my C++ program I open it and write commmands pro grammatically and my C++ program will execute commands on that batch file. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by opening a *pipe*. In brief:

```
FILE *bat = popen("path\\abc.bat", "w");
fprintf(bat, "first command\n");
fprintf(bat, "second command\n");
pclose(bat);
```

The text you write to `bat` will end up on the standard input of the batch file.

Comment: I tried this code:                                                    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 FILE *bat = popen("E:\\Softwares\\android-sdk_r10-windows\\android-sdk-windows\\tools\\abc.bat", "w");
 fprintf(bat, "from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice\n");
 //fprintf(bat, "second command\n");
 pclose(bat);

return 0;
}                                                                    But i am getting compilation errors:                               'popen' : undeclared identifier

Comment: You appear to be running Windows. In that case, use `_popen()` and `_pclose()`.

Comment: Thank you friend, _popen() worked for me but still i have some problem. My C++ program just open that bath file but i can't see the command running on it :(

Comment: I am able to write that command on monkeyrunner batch file. Can you please tell me that how can i send ENTER command so that batch file understand that a command has been finished and it will execute it.Thanks.

Comment: If `\n` doesn't work, then try `\r`. What works depends on exactly how your batch file reads its input.

Comment: I tried \r as well but its not working. Is it possible to write commands to batch file through C++ program or i am doing impossible things? Thanks

Comment: I don't know. You haven't shown anything about how your batch file *reads* its input.

Comment: I am using monkeyrunner batch file which comes in Android SDK package under Tools folder. We can manually launch this batch file and can give it python scripts to it which it runs. I want to do same thing using C++ program... Any ideas?